# Windows 10 is listed on Grub menu, even after uninstalling Windows 10

Tags: linux, boot, grub, arch-linux

I installed Linux on what previously was Windows partition. And everything is working fine except Windows 10 is listed on Grub Menu, even though I don't have Windows 10 anymore.

Comment: Clean up your ESP (i.e. remove ESP_MOUNTPOINT/EFI/Microsoft, where ESP_MOUNTPOINT is usually /boot/efi or /boot).

Answer (score 0):

See the article
[How to remove broken Grub boot entries on Linux](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/remove-broken-grub-boot-entries-on-linux/),
where is recommended using the tool Grub Customizer.
The article describes what needs to be done in Ubuntu, Debian,
Arch Linux, Fedora and OpenSUSE.

**Install Grub Customizer on Arch Linux**

Enable the “Community” software repository by uncommenting it in
`/etc/pacman.conf`.

Then install Grub Customizer directly from the “Community” repo with

```
sudo pacman -Syy grub-customizer
```

**Remove broken Grub boot entries**

Launch the Grub Customizer application, in the “List configuration” tab
find the entry, right-click it and select “Remove” in the context menu.

**Update Grub**

Run the command :

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Reboot to check that the Windows entry was indeed removed.

See the linked article for more information that includes screenshots.